# Call a stored procedure from VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm pretty new to SQL and VBA and I've written the following query in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_insert_search_archive 
    @IP_Address VARCHAR(20),
    @DT VARCHAR(30), 
    @search_word VARCHAR(50), 
    @search_time TIME
AS
    INSERT INTO Search_Archive
    values (@IP_Address, @DT, @search_word, @search_time);
```

Now I would like to execute this stored procedure in VBA (Excel):

```
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim par As String
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
StartTime = Timer

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 4)
Dim search_word As String
search_word = Range("D2").Text
Dim IP As String
IP = GetMyPublicIP

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("IP", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, IP)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DT", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Now)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Search Word", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, search_word)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Search Time", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, SecondsElapsed)
cmd.CommandText = "SP_insert_search_archive"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
MsgBox (DT)
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

When I'm activating the macro, I get this error:

> Runtime error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
>
> Procedure or function SP_insert_search_archive has too many arguments specified

Comment: Are you sure you have created this stored proc in 'master' database? Can you check this line ? 

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: yea i've checked and the SP is indeed under "master" DB

Comment: can you try creating your stored proc in any other database?

Comment: I ran your code but got a different error, "Error converting data type to time". ADO and the legacy SQLOLEDB provider only knows of data types in the SQL 2000 world so you need to convert the time value to a string in "HH:mm:ss" format for a `time` parameter on the server side.

Comment: i've changed from time to varchar(30) , try to ran it now :)

Answer (score 0):

possible that the issue is with the name of the parameters, you left spaces in them instead of separating with "_" ("Search Word" instead of "search_word")

Comment: AFAIK ADODB uses the order of the parameters rather than the name.  You can give the parameters whatever name you like as long as they are added in the right order